# Which URL is revealed when using wildcard SSL?

Tags: tls, wildcard

Assume there are two servers; `server1.com` has a standard SSL certificate installed and `server2.com` has a wildcard SSL certificate (*.server2.com) installed.

Next, assume you make from server 1 via SSL connection an API call to `api2.server2.com`...

If someone eavesdrops on the connection, which URL of server2 would the sniffer see?

Would the sniffer see `server2.com` or the subdomain that was called `api2.server2.com`?

Comment: Besides of SSL handshakes the eavesdropper could also see some DNS requests, which might reveal the actual called URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) extension, now implemented by most SSL libraries, implies that a sniffer would see the name `api2.server2.com` as part of the unencrypted `ClientHello` message from server1.

As for the rest of the URL (the path on server2), it is sent only after the handshake, so it is not visible to sniffers (but sniffers may still obtain a good estimate of the path *length*, in characters).